# Is there any way for Eclipse to handle async await (ES2017) in JavaScript without errors?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, frontend, ecmascript-2017

I have tried Wild Web Plugin and it still shows "Semi-colon expected" at the codes that use async.

Wild Web Plugin claims that it handles ES2018 (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wild-web-developer-web-development-eclipse-ide), but it's not true.

I use Generic Editor to make sure that the Wild Web Plugin is applied.

I can use Visual Studio Code for that, but it would be nice to have all inside Eclipse.

Is there any free alternative to do that?

P.D: Versions.

ECLIPSE

Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)

Build id: 20190917-1200

WILD WEB

Wild Web Developer - Developer and debug Web and Node applications    0.7.1.201910241910  org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Wild Web Developer project

Comment: The CodeMix plugin can handle this for you, inside Eclipse. Not free, but you can try it for about 45 day for free, quite sure it's worth the license cost.

Disclaimer: I work for Genuitec, makers of CodeMix, and other Eclipse solutions.

Comment: For my eclipse (2022-06 (4.24.0) ) the only way to get rid off the error is to rename my script file (it happens to be a es6 module) from "name.js" to "name.mjs" . Other errors are still highlighted, so the Syntax check is not turned off. Somehow, eclipse seems to apply a different syntax check for modules. However, async functions are not restricted to modules and the suffix ".mjs" for modules is not mandatory (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#aside_%E2%80%94_.mjs_versus_.js)). So the fact that eclipse complains is indeed quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, using the **generic text editor** for my js file with async functions instead of the obvious "Nodeclipse Nodejs Editor", the errors "needs semicolon: went away.
My Eclipse IDE is   2020-09 (4.17.0).

Comment: this doesn't work for me, unfortunately (2022-06 (4.24.0)). Only a renaming ".js" to ".mjs" helps for me, but obviously this solution makes sense only for modules ...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug report](https://github.com/eclipse-wildwebdeveloper/wildwebdeveloper/issues/485) this is not a problem in Wild Web Developer but a similar and apparently unrelated plugin [Eclipse Web Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools). So the claim that Wild Web plugin handles ES2018 is probably true.

For me uninstalling "Eclipse Web JavaScript Developer Tools" (and "Eclipse Web Developer Tools" because it has the first as dependency) fixed the problem. No more "Semi-colon expected" for async.

Alternatively disabling Preferences -> Valdiation -> JavaScript Validation should work and not affect Wild Web Developer (not tested myself).

This can also explain why renaming the file to ".mjs" works. The JavaScript validation from this other plugin only checks ".js" files.